# getting the IntegrityError Message in Django view

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

I Have a complex model with 6 constrains and i want to get a message to the user which constrain failed when the post-request fails.

```py
 class testView(APIView):
    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
         serializer = testSerializer(data=request.data)

         if not serializer.is_valid():
             return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

         try:
             testModel.objects.create(
                 # all the data
             )
             return testView.get(request)
         except IntegrityError:
             return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

The exception is called but I cant find the specific constrain that faild in the `IntegrityError`class.

Is there any way to return the specific Constrain to the User?

(iam using django 3.0.2 with Postgresql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the actual error message from [exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/exceptions/#database-exceptions)

```
except IntegrityError as e:
    error_message = e.__cause__
```

> As per PEP 3134, a `__cause__` attribute is set with the original
>   (underlying) database exception, allowing access to any additional
>   information provided.

Comment: if I do this i get this error: `AttributeError: type object 'IntegrityError' has no attribute 'message'` did you tried it yourself?

Comment: It depends on version of python/django sorry pasted old one, now it is in args[0] or just use  \__cause__ as per PEP 3134

Comment: If you're going to check for a substring in `__cause__`, you need to stringify it, so maybe use `error_message = str(e.__cause__)`. But I think `error_message = e.args[0]` is cleaner.

Comment: e.args[0] could raise index error in cases there is no exception message, to be frank I am not having a particular example of it happening for this use case